# how to copy files from one folder to another folder(need folder merge and file overwrite on exist)

Tags: windows, batch-file, xcopy, robocopy

I need some help of copying file using command line robocopy or xcopy only please.

I have a bunch of files in subfolders in some subfolders of a folder like so.

```
EX:

source\subfolder1\anothersubfolder1\filename1
source\subfolder2\anothersubfolder1\filename1
source\subfolder1\anothersubfolder2\filename2
source\subfolder1\anothersubfolder2\filename2

dest\subfolder1\anothersubfolder1\filename1
dest\subfolder2\anothersubfolder1\filename1
dest\subfolder2\anothersubfolder2\filename2
dest\subfolder2\anothersubfolder2\filename2
dest\subfolder1\anothersubfolder2\filename3
dest\subfolder1\anothersubfolder2\filename4
```

I just need to merge both source and destination folders so if new file in source need to copy on destination but same file should be overwritten but I don't want to overwrite existing folders. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

```
xcopy /d /s /l "sourcedir\*" "destdir"
```

should report what it wants to do (the `/l` switch means "list only, don't execute. Removing the `/l` will actually execute the copy) and may suit your purpose. `/d` means "updated files only" so it will copy any updated friles in the source to the destintion along with files that do not currently exist at the destination.

Not sure about what you mean by not wanting to overwrite existing folders.

Comment: I mean to say that overwriting folders in my view is overwriting all the destination files with source files.  I just want to get new files from sources to destination which are not exist in destination folder